# Effecting delayed transitions on d3js mouseout events

Tags: d3.js

Here is an excerpt from my d3.js scatter plot.

```
svg.on("click", function() {
        d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").classed("hidden", true);
   });
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[x']);
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d['y']);
   })
   .attr("r", scatter_radius)
   .style("stoke", "gray")

   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log('mouseover: ' + d3.select(this));
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + scatter_radius;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
        d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01")
            .style("left", xPosition + "px")
            .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
            .select("#value_tt_01")
            .text(d['x'] + ',' + d['y']);

        d3.select(this).style("fill", 'red');
        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").classed("hidden", false);
   })
   .on("mouseout", function() {
        console.log('mouseout: ' + d3.select(this));
        d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").transition().delay(30).attr("class", "hidden");
        d3.select(this).transition().delay(30).style("fill", "gray");
   })
```

The attempts in the `mouseout` event to institutea delay before the tooltip disappears and a delay before the circle turns back are not working. The changes are made immediately.
How can this be done in `d3.js` ?

Comment: 30 miliseconds is too fast make the delay 1000 miliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").transition().delay(30)` is too fast.
make it `d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").transition().delay(1000)`

Moreover for a fading effect don't apply a class but apply style like this for hiding

`d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").transition().delay(1000).style("opacity", 0)`

For showing it back do:

`d3.select("#tooltip_svg_01").transition().delay(1000).style("opacity", 1)`

This one should work as expected:

`d3.select(this).transition().delay(30).style("fill", "gray");`

Just give a higher delay

`d3.select(this).transition().delay(1000).style("fill", "gray");`

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I should always double check whether I am working in seconds or milliseconds. Useful to know that `opacity` is the preferred style to deal with when using transitions.

Comment: Its not preferred...I have put it up there to give the slow hide effect. when you apply class it will be applied at once and you will not get the effect.